# Ajax data not being displayed after upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Currently my entire code is working almost flawlessly, how ever upon upload the ajax data is not being displayed on my webpage after a successful upload.

Below is the code I am using (completely) because I am rather new and have been reviewing various stack over flow posts to guide me in building this.

Sorry for lack of structure below.. I don't know how to adapt to stack overflows structure requirements..

The actual form input / submit

```
<form action="upload2.php" class="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload" method="post" name="upload">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Uplaod Files</legend> <input id="file" multiple name="file[]" required="" type="file"> <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="upload">
    </fieldset>
    <div class="bar">
        <span class="bar-fill" id="pb"><span class="bar-fill-text" id="pt"></span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="uploads" id="uploads"></div>
</form>
```

Here's the PHP code I am using to upload the file.

```
<?
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$upload = [];
$allowed = ['mp3', 'm4a'];

$succeeded = [];
$failed = [];

if (!empty($_FILES['file'])) {
    foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $key => $name) {
        if ($_FILES['file']['error'][$key] === 0) {
            $temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
            $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'][$key];

            $ext = explode('.', $name);
            $ext = strtolower(end($ext));
            $s = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 4)), 0, 4);
            $file = $s . '.' . $ext;
            $data = $file_name . PHP_EOL . $file_size;
            file_put_contents('d/' . $s . '.txt', $data);
            if (in_array($ext, $allowed) === true && move_uploaded_file($temp, "v/{$file}") === true) {
                $succeeded[] = array(
                    'name' => $name,
                    'file' => $file,
                );
            } else {
                $failed[] = array(
                    'name' => $name
                );
            }
        }
    }
    if (isset($_POST['ajax'])) {
        echo json_encode(array(
            'succeeded' => $succeeded,
            'failed' => $failed
        ));
    }
}
```

Below is javascript event listener + the returned data from ajax

```
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var f = document.getElementById('file'),
        pb = document.getElementById('pb'),
        pt = document.getElementById('pt');
    app.uploader({
        files: f,
        progressBar: pb,
        progressText: pt,
        processor: 'upload2.php',
        finished: function (data) {
            var uploads = document.getElementById('uploads'),
                succeeded = document.createElement('div'),
                failed = document.createElement('div'),
                anchor,
                span,
                x;
            if (data.failed.length) {
                failed.innerHTML = '<p>file didnt upload<\/p>';
            }
            uploads.innerText = '';
            for (x = 0; x < data.succeeded.length; x = x + 1) {
                anchor = document.createElement('a');
                anchor.href = 'uploads/' + data.succeeded[x].file;
                anchor.innerText = data.succeeded[x].name;
                archor.target = '_blank';
                console.log(anchor);
                succeeded.appendChild(anchor);
            }
            uploads.appendChild(succeeded);
        },
    });
});
```

Below is the javascript we're using for ajax (I think the issue is here but I keep reviewing it and I'm not able to find the problem.)

```
var app = app || {};
(function (o) {
    "use strict";
    var ajax, getFormData, setProgress;
    ajax = function (data) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(),
            uploaded;
        xmlhttp.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {
            if (this.readystate === 4) {
                if (this.status === 200) {
                    uploaded = JSON.parse(this.response);
                    if (typeof o.options.finished === 'function') {
                        o.options.finished(uploaded);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (typeof o.options.error === 'function') {
                        o.options.error();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        xmlhttp.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (event) {
            var percent;
            if (event.lengthComputable === true) {
                percent = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
                setProgress(percent);
            }
        });
        xmlhttp.open('post', o.options.processor);
        xmlhttp.send(data);
    };
    getFormData = function (source) {
        var data = new FormData(),
            i;
        for (i = 0; i < source.length; i = i + 1) {
            data.append('file[]', source[i]);
        }
        data.append('ajax', true);
        return data;
    };
    setProgress = function (value) {
        if (o.options.progressBar !== undefined) {
            o.options.progressBar.style.width = value ? value + '%' : 0;
        }
        if (o.options.progressText !== undefined) {
            o.options.progressText.innerText = value ? value + '%' : '';
        }
    };
    o.uploader = function (options) {
        o.options = options;
        if (o.options.files !== undefined) {
            ajax({});
            ajax(getFormData(o.options.files.files));
        }
    }
}(app));
```

My file is uploading, the progress bar is working and without returning `e.preventDefault();` when it redirect to `upload2.php` I'm able to see the contents of the `json` i really don't know what my problem could be..

Comment: Can someone format please?

Comment: What do you see in developers console?

Comment: I wonder, why not use JQuery? It implements AJAX and works.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware was wondering the same, would be a bit of a pain for him to re edit now though

Comment: @u_mulder I don't see any errors in my developers console.. also where I am returning this `console.log(anchor);` it does not display in my developers console either.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware While jQuery is a great help it doesn't hurt to learn how to do things without it. Also, while hard to see with the wall of code, the issue might have nothing to do with the ajax request itself...maybe,..not sure, too much code.

Comment: try to parse your response ... JSON.parse(response)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a typo in **anchor** here:

```
archor.target = '_blank';
```

Maybe this throws error and stops other code execution

Also you could check if your **uploads** div is visible via element inspector in browser.

If console.log shows nothing - do you mean by this it is not even called or it shows *undefined*? If it doesn't show at all, then look into the for that uses *data.succeeded.length* param as a limit - maybe it equals 0 and thus console.log is never called

Comment: @MacBooc a**r**chor - should be anchor instead (second letter)